# How can I parse empty/null/nil value for a column with int type declared in struct from gherkin datatable in golang?

Tags: go, gherkin

I want to convert gherkin datatable values into struct. In that struct I have an attribute that has int type declared. How am I supposed to fill values in case there is no data in the gherkin datatable? In the present scenario it throws an error.

Here is the feature file

```
Feature: send request
  In order to be a rest tester
  I need to be able to make rest requests to server

  Scenario: GET request are allowed
    When I send "GET" request to "http://localhost:3000/posts/"
    Then the response code should be 200
    And the response from server should match:
    | Id | Title | Author | Worth |
    | 1 | json-server | typicode |  |
```

Here is the corresponding struct:

```
type response struct {
    Id     int    `json:"id"`
    Title  string `json:"title"`
    Author string `json:"author"`
    Worth int `json:"worth"`
}
```

Converting it into struct using this line of code :

```
assist := assistdog.NewDefault()
expectedStruct := &response{}
result, err2 := assist.CreateSlice(expectedStruct, dataTable)
```

I am getting error for this case. Can anyone please help me out?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I tried this and it seems that assistdog does not support pointers. You will have to consider using a different approach

Comment: I say seem, but I looked at the source. Assistdog definitely does not support int pointers

Comment: Here is the error for the case 
"
Error: failed to parse table as slice of *main.response:
row 0:
  - Watch: strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax . "